# How can I turn an enumerable into an AsyncEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have some code that uses the async extension methods available in Entity Framework Core:

```
public async Task<MyResult> DoQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable)
{
    var count = await queryable.CountAsync();
    var firstItems = await queryable
        .Take(5)
        .ToArrayAsync();

    return new MyResult(count, firstItems);
}
```

This works great when the `IQueryable` I give the function comes straight from EF. I also wanted to reuse this code to do some logic on a LINQ-to-objects "query":

```
var evens = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
var result = DoQuery(evens.AsQueryable());
```

This fails (which isn't too surprising):

> System.InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IEntityQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

It looks like a refactor is in order, but I'm curious: is there any way to turn a plain enumerable into a "dummy" `AsyncEnumerable` or `AsyncQueryable` that treats `CountAsync` synchronously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not have been available when the question was asked. It might not cater for the specific EF situation you are asking for. To directly answer the title of your question: "How can I turn an enumerable into an AsyncEnumerable?" or the one in the body of your question: "turn a plain enumerable into a "dummy" AsyncEnumerable...?"

The `System.Linq` namespace has native support for `ToAsyncEnumerable()` which does the job (there are several overloads)

If that was not available for whatever reason, you could implement it yourself like so:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> AsAsyncEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    foreach(var value in input)
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Example usage:

```
public async Task Test()
{
    var data = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var result = data.AsAsyncEnumerable();
    await foreach (var i in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for when this question was the first result. Thanks!

Comment: How can this method work?  I thought that all `async` methods had to perform an `await`?  In fact, this won't even compile when I add it to static class

Comment: The answer to your second question: this code does generate a compiler warning, but not an error: _"warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."_. Possibly it won't compile for you because your project is setup to treat compiler warnings as errors or there is another issue?

Comment: As for your first question, it's to do with the nature of how `yield return` works. I don't have time for a lengthy explanation in a comment but you can have non async code that  behaves sort of in an async manner. Setup a method that returns an IEnumerable with `yield return` inside. Loop over the result collection and do something with each element. If you debug that you'll see execution flip between the calling code and your method.

Comment: I have added some example code to my answer. Change the extension method to return, e.g. `yield return 2 * value` and if you debug through you should see the evaluation of `2 x 2` happen after the first result is printed in the system console, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an in-memory `DbAsyncQueryProvider` to process the async query. There is a detailed explanation on how to do that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async). Scroll to the part about *Testing with async queries*. Below is the code copy & pasted from that link:

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Linq.Expressions; 
using System.Threading; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

namespace TestingDemo 
{ 
    internal class TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IDbAsyncQueryProvider 
    { 
        private readonly IQueryProvider _inner; 

        internal TestDbAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner) 
        { 
            _inner = inner; 
        } 

        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression) 
        { 
            return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression); 
        } 

        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression) 
        { 
            return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression); 
        } 

        public object Execute(Expression expression) 
        { 
            return _inner.Execute(expression); 
        } 

        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression) 
        { 
            return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression); 
        } 

        public Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
        { 
            return Task.FromResult(Execute(expression)); 
        } 

        public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
        { 
            return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression)); 
        } 
    } 

    internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T> 
    { 
        public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) 
            : base(enumerable) 
        { } 

        public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression) 
            : base(expression) 
        { } 

        public IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator() 
        { 
            return new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator()); 
        } 

        IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator() 
        { 
            return GetAsyncEnumerator(); 
        } 

        IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider 
        { 
            get { return new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this); } 
        } 
    } 

    internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T> : IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> 
    { 
        private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner; 

        public TestDbAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner) 
        { 
            _inner = inner; 
        } 

        public void Dispose() 
        { 
            _inner.Dispose(); 
        } 

        public Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
        { 
            return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext()); 
        } 

        public T Current 
        { 
            get { return _inner.Current; } 
        } 

        object IDbAsyncEnumerator.Current 
        { 
            get { return Current; } 
        } 
    } 
}
```